# Python regex check if string contains any of words

Tags: python, regex

I want to search a string and see if it contains any of the following words: `AB|AG|AS|Ltd|KB|University`

I have this working in javascript:

```
var str = 'Hello test AB';
var forbiddenwords= new RegExp("AB|AG|AS|Ltd|KB|University", "g");

var matchForbidden = str.match(forbiddenwords);

if (matchForbidden !== null) {
   console.log("Contains the word");
} else {
   console.log("Does not contain the word");
}
```

How could I make the above work in python?

Comment: Just to stir up the pot... If you're optimization-crazy, you could use `University|A[BGS]|Ltd|KB` or `Ltd|University|[AK]B|A[GS]`... But when you need to change it, that's a hell to maintain! :)

Comment: Beware, what you are actually searching is a string pattern and not a true word : it will find following string"aa aABb cc" where a real *word* search should not.

Answer (score 9):

```
import re
strg = "Hello test AB"
#str is reserved in python, so it's better to change the variable name

forbiddenwords = re.compile('AB|AG|AS|Ltd|KB|University') 
#this is the equivalent of new RegExp('AB|AG|AS|Ltd|KB|University'), 
#returns a RegexObject object

if forbiddenwords.search(strg): print 'Contains the word'
#search returns a list of results; if the list is not empty 
#(and therefore evaluates to true), then the string contains some of the words

else: print 'Does not contain the word'
#if the list is empty (evaluates to false), string doesn't contain any of the words
```

Comment: It would be nice if you could add a little more explanation to your answer to help the person asking the question understand why this might help him.

Answer (score 6):

You can use re module. Please try below code:

```
import re
exp = re.compile('AB|AG|AS|Ltd|KB|University')
search_str = "Hello test AB"
if re.search(exp, search_str):
  print "Contains the word"
else:
  print "Does not contain the word"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
str="Hello test AB"
to_match=["AB","AG","AS","Ltd","KB","University"]
for each_to_match in to_match:
    if each_to_match in str:
        print "Contains"
        break
else:
    print "doesnt contain"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [findall](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) to find all matched words:

```
import re

s= 'Hello Ltd test AB ';

find_result = re.findall(r'AB|AG|AS|Ltd|KB|University', s)

if not find_result:
    print('No words found')    
else:
    print('Words found are:', find_result)

# The result for given example s is
# Words found are: ['Ltd', 'AB']
```

If no word is found, that `re.findall` returns empty list. Also its better not to use `str` as a name of veritable, since its overwriting build in function in python under the same [name](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#str).

Comment: `if re.findall(needles, haystack): print 'Found' else: 'No luck'` would be more inline with what the OP's original javascript.

Comment: Is there a way to make this only match if the word `AB` matches? Currently it also matches if `AB` is somewhere in another word

Comment: @Alosyius The simple solution would: `find_result = re.findall(r'\s+(AB|AG|AS|Ltd|KB|University)\s+', s)`. This assumes that there are spaces around a world. Obviously for periods, comas, and all other possible ways a word can appear in a sentence, something more complicated is needed.